# Performance difference in for loop condition?

Tags: c++, loops, logical-operators, comma-operator

I have a simple question that I am posing mostly for my curiousity.

What are the differences between these two lines of code? (in C++)

```
for(int i = 0; i < N, N > 0; i++)

for(int i = 0; i < N && N > 0; i++)
```

The selection of the conditions is completely arbitrary, I'm just interested in the differences between , and &&.

I'm not a beginner to coding by any means, but I've never bothered with the comma operator.

Are there performance/behavior differences or is it purely aesthetic?

One last note, I know there are bigger performance fish to fry than a conditional operator, but I'm just curious.  Indulge me.

*Edit*
Thanks for your answers.

It turns out the code that prompted this question had misused the comma operator in the way I've described.  I wondered what the difference was and why it wasn't a && operator, but it was just written incorrectly. I didn't think anything was wrong with it because it worked just fine.  Thanks for straightening me out.

Comment: Why are you worried about performance? In the time it takes to get an answer to this question, the 9 nanoseconds you would have saved using one or the other notation would already be lost. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil..."

Comment: He didn't say he was worried - just curious. I really wish people would stop waving the "premature optimization" flag every time someone "just wants to know". Curiosity is a *good thing*.

Comment: I wonder how much time would be saved if SO implemented a filter that, every time anyone mentions the words "performance" or "faster" in a question, just auto-posts a comment saying, "you're not allowed to think about that, citizen, now get back to work" ;-)

Comment: "Premature quoting of Knuth is the root of much other evil." -- Me

Comment: "Premature doing anything is evil, that is how premature defined:)" -- Me

Comment: As I said, the performance issue is minimal and merely asked for my curisotity.  I was mostly interested in the functionality differences.  I've retagged to remove the performance tag.  However, I will say that this is a loop, and for all we know N could be 100000000042 or some other random large number.  If that is the case, the performance difference could add up quickly.

Comment: You aren't alone in not bothering with the comma operator, it's just not very useful. And it can lead to bugs, as you've just found. The only time I use it is in the first or third expression of a for loop, to initialize or increment two variables at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although it looks like it,

```
for(int i = 0; i < N, N > 0; i++)
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < N && N > 0; i++)
```

are not equivalent.

Here is the proof.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int N = 10;
  int i = 5;

  int val = (N, i);
  cout << val << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
5
```

Which means that the when determining when the loop will exit it will use `N > 0`.
If `N = 10`, this means that it will always be true and the loop will never exit.

Run this and see the proof.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int N = 10;
  int i = 5;

  for(int i = 0; i < N, N > 0; i++){
     cout << val << endl;
  }
}
```

---

```
bash-2.05$ ./a.out                  
0                                   
1                                   
2                                   
3                                   
4                                   
5                                   
6                                   
7                                   
8                                   
9                                   
10                                  
11                                  
...
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
^C
```

If N is a constant or variable that doesn't change inside the loop
then you could just remove the `N > 0` check by checking it once first, i.e.

```
if (N > 0){
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why no one voted this up.  I like a well thought out and detailed answer when I ask for an explaination.  Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't vote it up because it doesn't clearly state the difference, and tries to determine the meaning by experiment, rather than looking at the standard or any documentation.

Comment: I like examples and experiments personally.  RichieHindle's answer was short and accurate, but not very descriptive nor did it answer my question what is the actual difference.  Even if this answer didn't detail the reason behind the problem, it did actually answer the question.

Comment: What do you do when the standard says it "should" do X but is actually doing Y?  Compilers can have bugs too! Demonstration through experimentation shows the differences.

Comment: Read standards and other documentation first, test on specific implementations second.  That's my ranking, anyhow.  If the compiler has a bug, then at least you know its a bug and won't be surprised if it gets fixed in the future.

Answer (score 33):

Using a comma like that will simply **discard the first condition**.

The comma operator means "run these statements in this order, and take the value of the last one".

Comment: as in it totally ignores it and doesn't perform the check?

Comment: The value of "`i < N, N > 0`" is the same as the value of "`N > 0`".

Comment: @Victor: It compares i and N, discards the result, then compares N and 0 and uses the result to decide whether to continue the loop.  In optimised code, it will probably not bother to compare i and N.

Comment: The comparison will be performed, but the result will be discarded.